# TypeError: 'DictWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I get this this error and I cant seem to see what direction I need to go to solve the issue

```
 TypeError: 'DictWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

I get the error when trying to extract some data from the results of a lookup from an amazon seller api using this python code:

```
products_api = mws.Products(access_key, secret_key, seller_id, region='US')
products = products_api.list_matching_products(marketplaceid=marketplace_usa, query='XAZ')

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=1)
pp.pprint (vars(products))  # prints info below which contains the data I need
```

I figured I could use something like the command below to start to make my way through the results but i get the above error and google didnt put me a direction where I could solve the problem.  Ultimately I want to extract the 'brand' and a few other fields from the results.

```
a=products['_mydict']
```

..

```
{'_mydict': {'ListMatchingProductsResponse': {'ListMatchingProductsResult': {'Products': {'Product': [{'AttributeSets': {'ItemAttributes': {'Binding': {'value': 'Apparel'},
                                                                                                                                    'Brand': {'value': 'Crocs'},
                                                                                                                                        'Color': {'value': 'Tropical '
                                                                                                                                                           'Teal'},
                                                                                                                                        'Department': {'value': 'unisex-adult'},
                                                                                                                                        'IsAdultProduct': {'value': 'false'},
                                                                                                                                        'ItemDimensions': {'Height': {'Units': {'value': 'inches'},
                                                                                                                                                                      'value': '0.39'},
                                                                                                                                                           'Length': {'Units': {'value': 'inches'},
                                                                                                                                                                      'value': '0.39'},
                                                                                                                                                           'Weight': {'Units': {'value': 'pounds'},
                                                                                                                                                                      'value': '0.44'},
                                                                                                                                                           'Width': {'Units': {'value': 'inches'},
                                                                                                                                                                     'value': '0.39'}},
                                                                                                                                        'Label': {'value': 'crocs'},
                                                                                                                                        'ListPrice': {'Amount': {'value': '34.99'},.......
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation of `DictWrapper` in the [python-amazon-mws](https://github.com/python-amazon-mws/python-amazon-mws/blob/master/mws/mws.py#L101) library, the object received as a response is not a dictionary and shouldn't be used as one. This is also what the error message states.

However, the object has a property `parsed` which returns the response in the format of a dictionary. That is what you should use.

```
products = products_api.list_matching_products(marketplaceid=marketplace_usa, query='XAZ')
products_as_dict = products.parsed
products_as_dict['_mydict']
```

The object also contains an attribute offering the original XML output, in case you ever need it.

```
products_as_xml = products.original
```

Comment: I think is likely the issue and will test when in front if the computer.  How did you determine this?  I just assumed it was a dictionary and when pretty printing it the results looked like a dictionary.   Was it as simple as the error stating it was not scriptable?

Comment: @personalt The name suggested the object might be a dictionary, but the error message stated otherwise. That didn't make much sense, so the only thing left to be sure was to consult the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The dict is really complex. I reduced it a little, but this should work for you aswell:

```
print(products['_mydict']['ListMatchingProductsResponse']['ListMatchingProductsResult']['Products']['Product'][0]['AttributeSets']['ItemAttributes']['Brand'])
```

I think the problem is the nested list. In my example I simply used the first item  [0]. Maybe you will need an iteration here.

It prints:

```
{'value': 'Crocs'}
```